# Query based on enum value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query based on the value of an enum field. Essentially I have 3 values (categories) for the enum field, a, b and c respectively. I am attempting to populate a select field based on the results of the following query:

`SELECT * WHERE pid = $id AND group = 'a';`

I have tried this with and without single quotes and get the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax;` and have narrowed it down to being a lack of knowing how to query based on a specific enum value. I assumed this would work and see no reason for it not to so if I can be enlightened I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: bro you need to tell the database about the table name too :)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I do in the original script, assumed it would be assumed and just get to the juicy bits but i guess I should of put everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group is a reserved keyword use it like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pid = $id AND `group` = 'a';
```

Comment: I'll give that a try, by reserved keyword you mean it is already used elsewhere?

Comment: I should of included table name in my question, i do include that in the original script ie:  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid = $id...`

Comment: @user3070011. [mysql reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm, good catch, do you happen to know where a good list of reserved keywords is for future reference? Otherwise ill just try to find one via google. Thanks!

Comment: See the above comment

Answer (score 0):

Use tablename

```
 SELECT * From tablename WHERE pid = $id AND `group` = 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
SELECT * FROM tbname WHERE pid = $id AND `group` = 'a';
```